# Silencing constraint errors when hiding table view cell

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, constraints

I have a tableview which has a label inside each cell:

[image: tableview]

I have set three constraints for the label:

[image]

I am hiding some of the cells in code based on some condition by setting the height to zero and setting their isHidden property to true and when that happens, I get this in console:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c606e0 UILabel:0x157edf690'0'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x157edf250.topMargin + 2.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c60730 UITableViewCellContentView:0x157edf250.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x157edf690'0'.bottom + 2.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c60870 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x2836915e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x157edf250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c60e10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x157edf250.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c607d0 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2836915e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x157edf250 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c60730 UITableViewCellContentView:0x157edf250.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x157edf690'0'.bottom + 2.5   (active)>
```

now I have two questions:

1- Is it safe to ignore this warning?

2- I know that it may help to lower the priority in one of the constraints. but which one should it be and why?

Comment: Setting the bottom constraint to `750` ( or anything less than `1000` (required)) seems to resolve the errors in my testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried 999 and it works as well. However, do you think it is safe to ignore it altogether? I am just curious. Can it cause an app crash if ignored?

Comment: It’s annoying to see in the console, but I would not expect it to cause a crash. They auto layout system is breaking the bottom constraint to try resolve the inconsistency . Your label has some intrinsic content size based on the text, that plus the top and bottom constraints equal some height (say 25 points) but you set the cell height to zero. The auto layout system can’t resolve this conflict so it breaks the bottom constraint. Setting it to less than 1000 makes it optional (but try real hard) so the system doesn’t warn you anymore.

Comment: You might also want to consider just filtering the data source so it only contains the items you want displayed. Then you wouldn’t need to make the bottom constraint optional.